# How insert random number?

Tags: insert, text, numbers

Suppose I has text:

```
test hello
```

The cursor is after word **test**. I need to insert random number? Also I need to set range of random (e.g. from 0 to 1000)

The result maybe like this:

```
test100 hello
```

Comment: What is your question? Maybe, the following page answers it: http://www.wilkesley.org/~ian/xah/emacs/elisp_insert_random_number_string.html. An on-the-fly solution would be: `M-: (insert (format "%d" (random 1000)))`.

Comment: @tobias just curious, why link to that mirror instead of Xah's site? http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_insert_random_number_string.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lisp
(defun my-random-number-insert-at-point ()
  "Insert a random number between 0 and 1000."
  (interactive)
  (insert (number-to-string (random 1000))))
```

Comment: Don't call `(random t)` since it should be unnecessary.  Also, please indent your code properly so it's more readable.  Also, you may like to check the consistency between your docstring and your code ;-)